# How to connect to SFTP through Paramiko with SSH key and Pageant

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, private-key, pageant

I am trying to connect to an SFTP through Paramiko with a passphrase protected SSH key. I have loaded the key into Pageant (which I understand is supported by Paramiko) but I can't get it to decrypt my private key.

I have found this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490228/how-to-use-pageant-with-paramiko-on-windows) that references `allow_agent=True` but this does not appear to be a parameter that can be used with the `SFTPClient`.

Can anyone advise if it is possible to work with Paramiko and Pageant in this way?

This is my code at the moment - which raises `PasswordRequiredException`

```
privatekeyfile = 'path to key'
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile)
transport = paramiko.Transport(('host', 'port'))
transport.connect('username',pkey = mykey)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to provide a passphrase, when loading an encrypted key using the [`RSAKey.from_private_key_file`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.from_private_key_file).

Though note that you do *not* have to load the key *at all*, when using the Pageant. That's the point of using an authentication agent. But only the [`SSHClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html) supports the Pageant. The `Transport` class does not, on its own.

You can follow the code in [How to use Pageant with Paramiko on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8490228/850848)
Though as the `allow_agent` is `True` by default, there is actually *nothing special* about the code.

Once connected and authenticated, use the [`SSHClient.open_sftp` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.open_sftp) to get your instance of the `SFTPClient`.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, username='user', allow_agent=True)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

You will also need to verify the host key:
[Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
privatekeyfile = 'path to key'
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile)
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.connect(hostname='host', username='user', allow_agent=True, pkey=mykey)

ftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()

print(ftp_client.listdir('/'))
```